# Edit all jpeg from folder and subfolder with GD PHP

Tags: php, compression, jpeg, gd

I want to compress some folders of jpgs and I want to use GD for this task but I'm having troubles getting it to work. I can compress single files and overwrite them with this code easily:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("descriptionImage11.jpg");  

imagejpeg($img,"descriptionImage11.jpg",50);
```

but I'm not quite sure how now to edit every image in a folder and it's subfolder and overwrite them with the new, compressed, version.

It would be nice if someone could provide some help.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php if you have a really big directory.

Comment: So I can just add set_time_limit(1000); and the script would run for 1000 seconds even if I get a 500 error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate over all directories using the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

```
<?php

$di  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./');
$iter  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di);
$regexIter = new RegexIterator(
$iter, '/^.+\.jpg$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach ($regexIter as $fileInfo) {
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileInfo[0]);  
  imagejpeg($img,$fileInfo[0], 50);
}
```

Comment: This returns me with a "Call to a member function getPathname() on a non-object on line 6" error message.

Comment: There was a typo in the case of "i" in `$fileInfo`. I have fixed it.

Comment: This actually does change something, I just realized that it compressed a dummy image I used for testing in my root named "descriptionImage11.jpg" but I need it to change multiple jpgs with different names.

Comment: I made the transform general, try now.

Comment: This works but it doesn't affect sub folders. I have an image folder with a few hundreds of folders so doing that manually would be pretty inefficient and boring haha.

Comment: I have made it recursive

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again but this sadly does not work. I thought it worked but then saw the error message (multiple times): "Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 9". Can you help me once again ?

Comment: Ah, thats right `RegexIterator` returns an array of matches so it should be `$fileInfo[0]`

Comment: Any way of making this just select one folder and it's subfolders ? My page is returning me with a timeout because of the time the script requires, maybe another fix for this issue ?